# frequency of MCP3008

Tags: voltage, switches, frequency, boost, converter

I built BOOST CONVERTER,
I sample the output voltage with A/D and control it
using RASPBERRY Pi3, I set the switching frequency of the BOOST CONVERTER 70KHz,
and the frequency of the MCP3008 1.35MHz,
is that right? and what is the connection between the switch frequency of the converter
and the frequency of the A/D?

Comment: Not enough info to say if your choices are "right".  It depends on your system specs.  Your control loop bandwidth should be about 1/10 of the switching frequency, (but watch for the right half-plane zero) so your minimum sampling frequency should be more than twice that.  To be safe 10X the control bandwidth would be a good choice, so in that case the sampling and switching frequency would be equal.  You have to compute the compensation between each sample period so that may be a consideration too.

Comment: @JohnD why My control loop bandwidth should be about 1/10 of the switching frequency??

Comment: @hos，Welcome and nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. Your project is interesting, but spec not clear. So let me ask a couple of questions to clarify. (1)  What is the operation principle? Beside the ADC, do you have a capacitor to store the boosted voltage, and do you have a switch to control the current/charge to the cap? (2) Do you have any device as a model to learn from? eg MT3608, XL6009? (3)  Now about your MCP3008 question, I vaguely remember MCP3008 max sample rate is 200kHz, and that each sample takes 3 SPI read/write byte cycles./ to continue, ...

Comment: In other words, it is not the SPI speed, say ranging from 100kHz to 10MHz that counts, it is the sampling frequency that is critical. Eg, if you SPI speed is too high, you cannot fill the ADC's internal sample and hold cap in time, but if your SPI speed is too slow, say below 50kHz, the sample and hold cap's charge might leak away too quickly. (4) your "frequency" of boost converter is a bit too vague. As I said, you can refer to MT3608 or XL6009 to specify, compare and contrast your design parameters. As I remember, MT3608 is using PFM, (not PWM), so design is complicated. / to continue, ...

Comment: Please feel free to ask me (@tlfong01) newbie boost converter questions. Have a great project. Cheers.

Comment: @hos It's a sampled data system- If you sample every switching cycle, (and there's no point in sampling faster) there's a zero-order hold which means a significant phase shift in the open loop transfer function as you approach the switching/sampling frequency.  If you want reasonably good phase margin then you typically wind up closing the loop at 1/10 or maybe if you push it as far as you can 1/5 of the switching/sampling frequency.  Since you are working on a boost converter, the right half-plane zero may limit you further.